# First empty row of openpyxl sheet is [] rather than [None]

Tags: python, openpyxl

I made Google spreadsheet similar to the image below and downloaded it as an xlsx.

[image: sheet.xlsx]

As you can see, the first row of the sheet is fully empty.

```py
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

sheet = openpyxl.load_workbook("sheet.xlsx", read_only=True)
ws = sheet['Sheet 1']
arr = np.array([[cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows()])
print(arr)
```

I expected this.

```
[[None None None None None]
 [None 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
 [None 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0]
 [None 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0]
 [None 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0]]
```

but it actually output this:

```py
[list([]) list([None, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
 list([None, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]) list([None, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0])
 list([None, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0])]
```

I tried to change it; I added one more empty row and ran the program again: [image: sheet2]

and it is showing this:

```py
[list([]) list([None, None, None, None, None])
 list([None, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]) list([None, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0])
 list([None, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]) list([None, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0])]
```

First row and Second row are exactly same(fully empty). but result like below.

WHAT? Why is it different?!

```py
FIRST_ROW = list([])
SECOND_ROW = list([None, None, None, None, None])
```

Finally I found that it gives this expected result when I remove `read_only` parameter from `load_workbook()`!

But I need to use the `read_only` option because the xlsx file that I want to load is a VERY BIG FILE.

Comment: Why does it matter if the 0th indexed row is `[]`? There wouldn't be any useful information in that row anyways.

Comment: @Filip Because I think it distort 2 dimension array to 1 dimension array when include 0th indexed when Its `[]`. Its also got something wrong when Its not fully empty. [other case](https://i.imgur.com/cKSOabJ.png) I think It can be handled by exception but Its not beauty. sry =(. Im not native so my English is not good.

Comment: The `list()` function converts the items inside to a list, so 1-dimensional list is actually a 2-dimensional list. Also all the items in `list()` are lists so I think you should be able to parse them, by treating it like a 2D list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In read-only mode, openpyxl returns exactly what it finds in the file, which in the first row is no cells at all. Because Google Sheets does not save the dimensions of the worksheet then there is no way to know how wide rows should be. This is fine as long as you intend to loop over the rows (which is the best way to proceed), but if you want a reliable number of cells in a row then you will have to set `min_col` and `max_col` parameters in `ws.iter_rows()`